# Word / Access VBA total

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I need help with vba word table column calculation.  My Word table is created in a Word template using Access database VBA. I need to to calculate the sum for the last column of the table.  But my table has no defined number of rows.  I have tried various options to no avail....  The following creates the table successfully and does a calculation, but only the last two rows of my table (currently 3 rows for the record I'm on) but does not calculate the sum for the whole column as hoped.  I can't work out what I'm missing?

```
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Set rs2 = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM InvoiceServiceLineItems WHERE InvoiceID=" & Forms!invoicedetail!ID, dbOpenSnapshot)

   With rs2
    .MoveLast
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
        End If
    End With

Dim indx As Integer
For indx = 1 To rs2.RecordCount
    With oDoc.Tables(3)
        .Cell(indx, 1).Range.Text = Nz(rs2![LineItemCode], "")
        .Cell(indx, 2).Range.Text = Nz(rs2![Description], "")
        .Cell(indx, 3).Range.Text = Nz(rs2![InitialTerm], "")
        .Cell(indx, 4).Range.Text = Format(Nz(rs2![UnitPrice], ""), "Currency")
        .Cell(indx, 5).Range.Text = Nz(rs2![Quantity], "")
        .Cell(indx, 6).Range.Text = Format(Nz(rs2![LineTotal], ""), "Currency")
        If rs2.AbsolutePosition <> rs2.RecordCount = -1 Then .Columns(1).Cells.Add

        .Cell(indx, 6).AutoSum
    End With
    rs2.MoveNext
Next indx
```

Comment: I don't follow the logic at the start.  You .MoveLast, then check for .EOF.  Then if it's NOT .EOF (how would it not be?) you do another .MoveLast? then a .MoveFirst?  So how does the recordset start at the beginning if the first .MoveLast does what it's supposed to do and moves to the last record - which is what should be happening every time.  You say it's only processing the last two records but by my reckoning it should only process one record - the last one.  Perhaps you only need to remove the first .MoveLast OR put the .MoveFirst unconditionally after it all.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I tried different variations of everything including your insight, but still not getting my full expected total. Records are there but only two are being summed! Will keep battling. I'm vague on the objects possible but will add solution here if I ever succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you would want to set the autosum outside the loop, and also, the cell index for the sum total would be "recordcount+1".

You can also do the sum at the end using a separate query such as

```
SELECT sum(LineTotal) as querySumTotal FROM InvoiceServiceLineItems WHERE InvoiceID=" & Forms!invoicedetail!ID
```